# VBA add incremented values into combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

| am wondering how to populate items list for a combobox from value to value by increment of value?
The way I do it now is by hand via:

```
LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.AddItem "300"
```

In this example I am trying to add values from 300 to 650 by increment of 1

Could someone, please, share a code for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be fancy, you could use something like:

```
LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.List = [Row(300:650)]
```

But for future reference you should know about the `For` loop where you could `Step` through in a specified interval (1 by default)

```
For x = 300 To 650 'Step 1
    LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.AddItem x
Next
```

Comment: I am all about fancy :D, Thanks the first one code works perfectly! And the second one I can use for where I need an increment that's not 1 but, say, 5 or 10. Thanks, mate!

Comment: There's a problem with it however. I am using that selected value from this combobox to do some mathematical calculations and it seems like excel doesn't treat this value added like this as it did when it's via additem

Comment: @Eduards, can you explain the above through an example so people can reproduce what you are experiencing? If you feel this is a seperate question, you may open a new question for people to answer.

Comment: Nah, I figured it out. I'm just letting people know that if values are added via ".List" they can't be used in mathematical operations BUT if values are added using ".additem" then indeed can be used for math operations with the value. That's if in the equation the variable is set to be the combobox value

Comment: @Eduards, I cannot reproduce that issue as I can perfectly use items added through `.List` property in mathematical operations. Feel free to add this in your OP for us to have a look at.

Comment: Weird, because I couldn't, but anyways... it's all good now

Answer (score 5):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub AddIncrementedNrCombo()
  Dim i As Long, arr(350)
  For i = 300 To 650
        arr(i - 300) = i
  Next i

  LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.list = arr
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

A version allowing incrementing with a different increment:

```
Sub AddIncrementedNrCombo()
  Dim i As Long, arr(350), k As Long, inc As Long
  
  inc = 10 'it can be calculated
  For i = 300 To 650 Step inc
        arr(k) = i: k = k + 1
  Next i
  
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.list = arr
End Sub
```

**Edit2**:

```
Sub AddIncrementedNrComboVar()
  Dim i As Long, arr(), k As Long, mN As Long, mX As Long, inc As Long
  
  mN = 300 'min
  mX = 650 'max
  inc = 10
  ReDim arr(mX - nm)
  
  For i = mN To mX Step inc
        arr(k) = i: k = k + 1
  Next i
  
  ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
  LowerFilmWidth_ComboBox.list = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks, before I tried this a quick question, is it possible to define it with using an actual increment? I get that (350) is teh number of entries

Comment: @Eduards: Yes, it is, but I must better understand what you mean... Should it load numbers from ten to ten, for instance?

Comment: Yeah In case I need intervals between numbers = 10 or maybe "5" it would be handy If it is defined as Min to max value with increment = value

Comment: @Eduards: Does the updated code (after editing) what you mean? `inc` variable can be calculated in any way. If you need modifying the values between the incrementation takes places, Yes, it can e done, too. Do you need such a code? Edited again and placed a version for such a case, too...